# How to make a multi-color gradient effect in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

How would I go about creating moving gradient background?

Comment: I suggest to rename the question to. "How to make a multi color gradient effect in CSS?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A)** `CSS` can do a blur, if you make a tiny image with for example just 5x4 pixels of random colors have this image stretched to `100%` in `height` and `width` as the background of a `DIV` and apply a heavy blur on that, your result will probably look similar. However blur doesn't work on all browsers, so you would need a fallback solution for unsupported browsers.

**B)** Also you can define linear gradients in `CSS`. Theoretically, but I never tried this before, we could make multiple gradient `DIV` with minimal color differences layered on top of each other using `opacity` by `CSS` animation/transition to mix the layers over time.

The snippet below needs more tweaking because it doesn't work in all possible odd cases with browsers, also inside the snippet view there is some padding offset that was not visible in pure html because there is a body tag that's missing in the snippet. However you asked for getting some directions. I hope you can optimise this code and share your results with the community. It does work in macOS Safari as far as I could tell. Firefox and Chrome still jump to the end of transition directly. So I wish you happy tweaking!

```js
function startTransitions() {
  document.getElementById('gradient-top-left').style.opacity = "0.1";
  document.getElementById('gradient-top-right').style.opacity = "0.1";
  document.getElementById('gradient-bottom-left').style.opacity = "0.1";
  document.getElementById('gradient-bottom-right').style.opacity = "0.1";
  document.getElementById('colors').style.opacity = "1.0";
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  startTransitions();
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  margin: 0px;
  padding 0px;
}

#colors {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url(http://testing.2x2p.com/gradient/colors.png);
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  filter: blur(120px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(120px);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 6s ease-in-out 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 6s ease-in-out 1s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 6s ease-in-out 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 6s ease-in-out 1s;
  transition: opacity 6s ease-in-out 1s;
}

#gradient-top-left {
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, orange, white);
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out 2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out 2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out 2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out 2s;
  transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out 2s;
}

#gradient-top-right {
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, lightgreen, white);
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out 4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out 4s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out 4s;
  -o-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out 4s;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out 4s;
}

#gradient-bottom-left {
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, pink, white);
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 4;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out 3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out 3s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out 3s;
  -o-transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out 3s;
  transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out 3s;
}

#gradient-bottom-right {
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, lightblue, white);
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 6s ease-in-out 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 6s ease-in-out 1s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 6s ease-in-out 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 6s ease-in-out 1s;
  transition: opacity 6s ease-in-out 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <div id="colors">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="gradient-top-left">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="gradient-top-right">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="gradient-bottom-left">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="gradient-bottom-right">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```